# Passing dust compilation options to Gulp Dust task

Tags: dust.js, dustc

I would like to pass various dustc options to gulp-dust in my node application. For eg, How can I set amd, cwd in gulp-dust. I understand we can pass name and preserveWhiteSpace in compilation options. But, what about other options?

Code Snippet:

```js
var dust = require('gulp-dust');
...

gulp.task('buildTemplates', function(){

   gulp.src('templates/page.dust').
        pipe(dust()).  //How will I say I need dust.config.amd=true
        pipe.dest('dist');  

});
```

Comment: I've fixed it in gulp-dust for amd support by including amd in options. Replace pipe(dust()) with following snippet to get amd modules.                                                         pipe(dust({amd:true}))